# Force <summary> to behave as display:inline instead of inline-block

Tags: html, css, popup, inline, display

I would like to use the `<details>` / `<summary>` tags for pure CSS popups, but `<summary>` behaves as inline-block and I cannot change it to inline.

Is there any way to force `<summary>` to behave as display:inline instead of inline-block?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      summary {
        color: red;
      }
      
      summary::-webkit-details-marker {
        display: none;
      }

      details, summary {
        display: inline;
        /* hyphens: manual;/ */
        /* word-break: break-all; */
        /* overflow-wrap: anywhere; */
        /* white-space: unset; */
      }

      .mimic {
        color: darkseagreen;
        display: inline-block;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>
      I would like to use the &ltdetails&gt / &ltsummary&gt tags for
      pure CSS popups,
      <details>
        <summary>
            but &ltsummary&gt behaves as inline-block
        </summary>
        (I'm fine with &ltdetails&gt)
      </details>
      and I cannot change it to inline. Is there any way to force &ltsummary&gt
      to behave as display:inline instead of inline-block?
      <br><br>
      I would like to use the &ltdetails&gt / &ltsummary&gt tags for
      pure CSS popups,
      <span class="mimic">
        but &ltsummary&gt behaves as inline-block
      </span>
      and I cannot change it to inline. Is there any way to force &ltsummary&gt
      to behave as display:inline instead of inline-block?
      <p>
        Just start to play with the width of the viewport...
      </p>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run code snippet and inspect it... The element <details> as well as <summary> are inline.

Comment: what is the fial purpose ? a popup stand over the content usually, do you mean something like a tool tip, or do you want just to hide some portion of text ? however, that is not the purpose of details ;)

Comment: maybe starting from an inline box with a title attribute and a tabindex to catch the click would be what you need : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvGOggr

Comment: `details` works thank to js... so, is not pure (won't be inline even being inline). And its behaviour is device-browser-dependent. I hate this, but that is true - use js - simple `onclick` will be better than very fancy and complex css. Or use pure html element like  `span:hover::after{ content: attr(title)` `<span title="nice title">hover me </span>`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus The focus-tabindex-pointer-events solution is perfect for both controlwise and inlinewise, but I couldn't make tooltip's "width" reactive (enough). I've tried margin-auto, left-right-px/auto, width%. None of them worked unfortunately. Many thanks anyway

Comment: @G-Cyrillus By now I've figured it out how to make tooltip's width reactive enough. It is demonstrated here employing your control solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198437/1405507

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display: contents;` can do it but it will behave strangely:

```css
summary {
  color: red;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

details,
summary {
  display: contents;
  /* hyphens: manual;/ */
  /* word-break: break-all; */
  /* overflow-wrap: anywhere; */
  /* white-space: unset; */
}

.mimic {
  color: darkseagreen;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>
      I would like to use the &ltdetails&gt / &ltsummary&gt tags for
      pure CSS popups,
      <details>
        <summary>
            but &ltsummary&gt behaves as inline-block
        </summary>
        (I'm fine with &ltdetails&gt)
      </details>
      and I cannot change it to inline. Is there any way to force &ltsummary&gt
      to behave as display:inline instead of inline-block?
      <br><br>
      I would like to use the &ltdetails&gt / &ltsummary&gt tags for
      pure CSS popups,
      <span class="mimic">
        but &ltsummary&gt behaves as inline-block
      </span> and I cannot change it to inline. Is there any way to force &ltsummary&gt to behave as display:inline instead of inline-block?
<p>
  Just start to play with the width of the viewport...
</p>
</span>
```

Comment: Temani & @ black_blue: Both of your solutions are really great. I have had a chance to mark as accepted of Temani, but would do both. Answering @G-Cyrillus' question: you're right I should be more specific. I needed this for tooltips. Unfortunately once <details> is [open] it breaks the line after its content. Therefore I ended up with black blue's solution, as I realised that hover works with touch control also if for leaving a neutral area is touched. On a functionality vs simplicity balance, I'm fine with this approach. Cheers guys!

Comment: Summerizing the solutions:

• focus-tabindex-pointer-events is perfect controlwise and inlinewise, but tooltip's "width" isn't reactive (enough)
• :hover::after has limits controlwise as for leaving on touch screen you need to tap to a neutral area
• details-summary-display:contents is inline until details (tooltip) is closed, once it's open, a line break appears after </details>
• javascript: works with virtual-DOM: <span
  class="has-tooltip"
  onclick="this.getElementsByClassName('tooltip')[0]
    .classList.toggle('tooltip-show')"
>
  <span class="tooltip"></span>
</span>

Comment: If anyone stops by here, there is currently a Chromium quirk where the text after the disclosure element (like "and I cannot change" in the demo) will render on a new line, but it works fine in Firefox and Safari. Given the number of caveats with `details` element it is tempting to recommend going for a classic "invisible checkbox with a general sibling combinator" trick instead.