# Tooltip: position & full width (at the same time)

Tags: css, tooltip, css-position

What CSS would force a tooltip:-

- to be positioned just above its reference text and
- to take up the full width of its reference text's container

...at the same time?

[image]

By default, the length between the reference text's first and last characters are considered. How to make the reference text's most left and right edges to be considered the length for the absolutely positioned child element?

```css
.tooltip {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /* left: 0; */
        /* right: 0; */

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 5px));
        background-color: white;
        color: red;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      .has-tooltip {
        position: relative;
        outline: 1px solid black;
      }
      
      /* ########### NOT IMPORTANT ############ */

      body {
        text-align: justify;
      }

      .container {
        display: table-cell;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 595px;
      }

      .filler {
        color: gray;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <span class="filler">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
      </span>
      <span class="has-tooltip">
        The tooltip spreads between the first and last characters of this text.
        Is there any way to force the tooltip to take up the 
        full width of this reference text while at the same time
        it is also absolute positioned to this reference text.
          <span class="tooltip">
            Tooltip: position & full width (at the same time)?
          </span>
      </span>
      <span class="filler">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want the tooltip above the text + fit the content of it's text?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want the positioning to be? Is it to the edge of the container on the left?Also is the width to be the width of the container. I don’t understand what is meant by the edges of the reference text as in the example they equate to the edges of the container but if the reference text was very short the tooltip would be very narrow.

Comment: @AHaworth POSITIONING: tooltip's bottom should be near to has-tooltip's top (it's done already) | WIDTH: as you write: "the edges of the reference text as in the example they equate to the edges of the container" (this is what I am interested in)

Comment: Is a change to the HTML acceptable?

Comment: ...and what would you like to happen if the text in the tooltip goes over more than one line and/or there isn’t room for it above the text it refers to? Would it be safer to have it below the text it refers to?

Comment: HTML amendment is not a problem, but no jQuery please, and javascript as a last resort only. I'm after a general best practice, and more than happy to adapt my current markup.

Comment: Regarding available room for the positioning, yes having a condition would be great, thank you for asking, but the question is for what price. I can see little room to get away with this without javascript. The best would be two solutions: one auto conditional and another fix one where devs manually choose between two CSS sets (always above OR below).

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to get a tooltop positioned in relation to the text it is describing and have it positioned and sized in relation to the containing block.

The snippet here changes the original question by placing the tooltip after the text it describes, this is because I cannot work out what is being asked for if the tooltip is above and allow both the text within the tooltip to be of arbitrary length (maybe going over many lines) and it not cover its related text if the text is near the top of the displayed page.

The changes to the snippet in the question are: remove the top and transform CSS in .tooltip and replace with left:0; change the HTML so the text and its tooltip are in separate spans; put in a CSS rule that changes the tooltip appearance (display:block) if its sibling text has has-tooltip class

There is some tidying up to be done in terms of positioning tooltip - margins/padding - depending on exactly what look is required but I hope this gives a basic idea.

```css
.tooltip {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /* left: 0; */
        /* right: 0; */

        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        color: red;
        border: 1px solid red;
        left:0;
      }
      span.has-tooltip + span {
        display: block;
      }
      .has-tooltip {
        position: relative;
        outline: 1px solid black;
      }
      
      /* ########### NOT IMPORTANT ############ */

      body {
        text-align: justify;
      }

      .container {
        display: table-cell;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      .container, .tooltip {
        width: 595px;
      }

      .filler {
        color: gray;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <span class="filler">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
      </span>
      <span class="has-tooltip">
        The tooltip spreads between the first and last characters of this text.
        Is there any way to force the tooltip to take up the 
        full width of this reference text while at the same time
        it is also absolute positioned to this reference text.
      </span>
          <span class="tooltip">
            Tooltip: position & full width (at the same time)?
          </span>
      <span class="filler">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: The thing with this approach is that it tries to set the width (with no sufficient success) and leave the vertical positioning to the browser (= ignores it). Originally the opposite was true: vertically set, horizontally not. In the meantime I have figured it out how to do it and will share it shortly. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Both vertical and horizontal alignment requires relative positioning. The problem is that the alignments require different elements to align to, while we can use only one element.

So the problem can be rephrased as: can we substitute one out of the two relative positioning somehow?

Giving a try to ::before / ::after it has turned out that the vertical positioning can be substituted with them. The down side is that it is fixed: the tooltip is always above or always below to the reference text, but in return there is no javascript.

Making this solution complete with control too, I am combining it with another stackoverflow answer provided by [G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069910/force-summary-to-behave-as-displayinline-instead-of-inline-block#comment113298053_64069910) which employes "focus" and "tabindex". Finally, for completeness, some transition has also been applied.

```css
.has-tooltip-before::before {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 5px));
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.has-tooltip-after::after {
  transform: translateY(calc(1em + 5px));
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.has-tooltip-before:focus::before,
.has-tooltip-after:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.has-tooltip-before,
.has-tooltip-after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  color: black;
}

.has-tooltip-before:focus,
.has-tooltip-after:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  text-align: justify;
}

span {
  color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
  </span>
  <span 
    class="has-tooltip-before"
    tabindex="0"
    data-tooltip="TOOLTIP ABOVE: 
      positioned above the reference text
      ...AND at the same time...
      it takes up the full width of the parent's container.
      Employes pure CSS for both positioning & control.
      Works with both pointer and touch."
  >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
  </span>
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
  </span>
  <span 
    class="has-tooltip-after"
    tabindex="0"
    data-tooltip="TOOLTIP BELOW: 
      positioned below the reference text
      ...AND at the same time...
      it takes up the full width of the parent's container.
      Employes pure CSS for both positioning & control.
      Works with both pointer and touch."
  >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
  </span>
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, 
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, 
    pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
  </span>
</div>
```